# Multicols custom column width

Tags: multicol

I need to use `multicol` package to create columns of custom width. I am unable to figure out how to achieve this.

I would also need to switch from one column to another based on specific content.

Comment: I think the `parcolumns` might be more appropriate for your needs

Comment: @cmhughes, any link to a parcolumns example to suggest ?

Comment: @sylvainulg: Have a look at another of my questions on `parcolumns`: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51041/vspace-has-no-effect-in-parcolumns

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All the columns have to be the same width, so you do not explicitly set the column width, just set the number of columns and the inter-column space (`\columnsep`) and this implicitly sets the column width based on the current `\linewidth`.