# vspace has no effect in parcolumns

Tags: spacing, parcolumns

I have following template for my resume wherein I am trying to get rid of the space between two education fields (space between two university entries, this causes my resume to go to second page).
The code that I use is as belows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,20pt]{article}

\usepackage[total={6.5in,8.75in}, top=1.2in, left=0.9in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{parcolumns}

\pagestyle{fancy}
% Remove page numbers
\fancyfoot{}

\setlength{\headheight}{28pt}
\chead{%
  \fontsize{20.74pt}{24pt}\selectfont{}%
  Name\\%
  \fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont{}%
  Address, Phone Number, etc.; %
  \href{mailto:mail@gmail.com}{\nolinkurl{mail@gmail.com}}; %
  \href{http://www.google.com}{WWW}%
}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{parcolumns}[nofirstindent, colwidths={1=.15\linewidth}]{2}
  \colchunk[1]{%
  EDUCATION\\*
  \\*
  \\*
  \\*
  }
  \colchunk[2]{%
  \textbf{University of XXX, XXX}\hfill 2011 - 2013 (Expected)\\*
  Master of Science, Computer Science, 4.0/4.0\\*
  \\*
  \textbf{University of YYY, YYY}\hfill 2005 - 2009\\*
  Bachelor of Technology, Computer Science, 10.0/10.0
  }
\end{parcolumns}
\end{document}
```

which produces following pdf:

[image: pdf]

I tried putting in `\vspace{<some-num>mm}` between two university entries so as to reduce the gap, but `\vspace` has no effect.

Can somebody help me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: Just something that confuses me: If you're using `parcolumns`, why pad out the left side with `\\*`'s? The package is designed to handle that automatically.

Comment: @rdhs: `parcolumns` vertically centers the left column w.r.t right one where as I want the left column to top aligned. I am not sure why by default `parcolumns` does not top align the left column instead of center aligning it. That seems to be the reasonable default logic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are better ways of obtaining your output. However, I assume you already have a setup in place, and changing it now might be a moot point. As such, consider using `\\*[<len>]` to have a fixed length `<len>` vertical skip between entries:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[total={6.5in,8.75in}, top=1.2in, left=0.9in]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{fancyhdr}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr
\usepackage{hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref
\usepackage{parcolumns}% http://ctan.org/pkg/parcolumns

\pagestyle{fancy}
% Remove page numbers
\fancyfoot{}

\setlength{\headheight}{28pt}
\chead{%
  \fontsize{20.74pt}{24pt}\selectfont{}%
  Name\\%
  \fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont{}%
  Address, Phone Number, etc.; %
  \href{mailto:mail@gmail.com}{\nolinkurl{mail@gmail.com}}; %
  \href{http://www.google.com}{WWW}%
}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{parcolumns}[nofirstindent, colwidths={1=.15\linewidth}]{2}
  \colchunk[1]{%
  EDUCATION\\*
  \\*[.5\baselineskip]
  \\*
  }
  \colchunk[2]{%
  \textbf{University of XXX, XXX}\hfill 2011 - 2013 (Expected)\\*
  Master of Science, Computer Science, 4.0/4.0\\*[.5\baselineskip]
  \textbf{University of YYY, YYY}\hfill 2005 - 2009\\*
  Bachelor of Technology, Computer Science, 10.0/10.0
  }
\end{parcolumns}
\end{document}
```

In the above example, the skip between items is given by `.5\baselineskip` (half a line skip). Modify this to suit your preference.

Comment: Hi Werner, thanks for the answer. Can you please explain why your answer is better than the one suggested by S. Murugan. I guess both of the approaches are doing more or less the same thing, right?

Is it a matter of better programming practice or something?

Comment: @abhinavkulkarni: Since `\\ ` already allows for a length-specification, it seems obvious to use it rather than inserting an negative `\vspace`.

Answer (score 1):

Check this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,20pt]{article}

\usepackage[total={6.5in,8.75in}, top=1.2in, left=0.9in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{parcolumns}

\pagestyle{fancy}
% Remove page numbers
\fancyfoot{}

\setlength{\headheight}{28pt}
\chead{%
  \fontsize{20.74pt}{24pt}\selectfont{}%
  Name\\%
  \fontsize{8pt}{9.6pt}\selectfont{}%
  Address, Phone Number, etc.; %
  \href{mailto:mail@gmail.com}{\nolinkurl{mail@gmail.com}}; %
  \href{http://www.google.com}{WWW}%
}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{parcolumns}[nofirstindent, colwidths={1=.15\linewidth}]{2}
  \colchunk[1]{%
  EDUCATION\vspace*{6pt}\\*
  \\*
  \\*
  }
  \colchunk[2]{%
  \textbf{University of XXX, XXX}\hfill 2011 - 2013 (Expected)\\*
  Master of Science, Computer Science, 4.0/4.0\vspace*{-6pt}\\*
  \\*
  \textbf{University of YYY, YYY}\hfill 2005 - 2009\\*
  Bachelor of Technology, Computer Science, 10.0/10.0
  }
\end{parcolumns}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain why this happens?
Why does /vspace{10pt} not work while /vspace*{-6pt} works?